# react-native-webview Navigate to a user defined uri

Tags: react-native, react-native-webview

Before posting this question, I found many tutorials regarding the react-native-webview component.  Unfortunately none of the very basic tutorials showed how to do anything beyond implementing a basic forward/backwards navigation.  I also did a quick check of the documentation, hoping to find an example of updating the uri of a webview after it has already been loaded.  Here is my attempt, can someone please tell me how to make this functionality work?

```
export default function App() {
  const [uriInput, setUri] = useState();
  const webviewRef = useRef();

  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
      <TextInput
        onChangeText={(text) => {
          setUri(text);
        }}
        style={styles.input}
      />
      <Button
        title="Go!"
        onClick={() => {
          webviewRef.source = { uri: uriInput };
        }}
      />
      <WebView
        ref={webviewRef}
        style={styles.webView}
        source={{ uri: "http://example.com" }}
      />
    </View>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Solved this myself.

```
export default function App() {
  const [uriInput, setUri] = useState();
  const [navUri, setNavUri] = useState();

  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
      <TextInput style={styles.input} onChangeText={(text) => setUri(text)} />
      <Button
        title="Go!"
        onPress={() => {
          setNavUri(uriInput);
        }}
      />
      <WebView source={{ uri: navUri }} />
    </View>
  );
}
```